# MongoDB - how can i set a documents limit to my capped collection?

Tags: python, mongodb

I'm fairly new to `MongoDB`. I need my `Python` script to query new entries from my `Database` in real time, but the only way to do this seems to be replica sets, but my `Database` is not a replica set, or with a `Tailable` cursor, which is only for capped collections.

From what i understood, a capped collection has a limit, but since i don't know how big my `Database` is gonna be and for when i'm gonna need to send data there, i am thinking of putting the limit to `3-4 million` documents. Would this be possible?.

How can i do that?.

Answer (score 1):

so do you want to increase the size of capped collection ?

if yes then if you know average document size then you may define size like: 
`db.createCollection("sample", { capped : true, size : 10000000, max : 5000000 } )`    here 5000000 is max documents with size limit of 10000000 bytes

Comment: This makes sense. Thank you!

Comment: for your reference https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/capped-collections/#restrictions-and-recommendations